# Zend Framework application.ini - 500 Internal server error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using zend framework 1.11. I'm getting 500 internal server error when i opening the url.
I have checked the database connection. It's fine. I don't know where is the problem exactly.

I'm getting the error from the line. $application->bootstrap()->run();
Please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: Check your web server/PHP error log to see what the actual error is.

Comment: And the actual error message is?

Comment: Web application have server logs as Tim Fountain and Ivan Husnjak said. Usually this are two files: `error.log` and `access.log` but location depends on OS and settings. You could also have different logs configured per web site. So check what's in there and you'll probably be able to solve this problem. If not come back here with the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the reasons are

1. rewrite module is not enabled.
2. htaccess is not configured to redirect
   request to index.php (usually in public folder)